# Avoid dialog box netbeans git prompting rebase or merge

Tags: git, netbeans

I'm trying to avoid prompt dialogs in NetBeans using Git.

Netbeans prompt me to "Pull changes" after pushing to remote repository, i select "Pull changes" and it prompts me again to merge/rebase when pushing to remote repository, i always select `merge`.

Is possible avoid that dialogs?  i changed global config adding:

```
[branch]
autosetupmerge always
autosetuprebase never
```

But no success... always prompt me again if other user pulls into repository previously...